# Mask outliers in an image

Tags: image-processing, image

I'm using Binarization/Morphological Operators to detect apples as objects, which has gotten me so far:

[image]

I did get the mask using this code

```
{c, r} = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[binarizedImg, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]; 
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Circle[c, r]}]]
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
disk = ColorConvert[ColorNegate@Graphics[{Black, Disk[c, r]}, ImageSize -> {w, h}], "Grayscale"]
dat = disk // ImageData;
```

What I want to do is: I want to mask the outliners in the image within the mask. Outliners means the pixels which are too bright (not necessarily saturated completely, but just too bright because of the used halogen lamps).

As I got the mask as a disk-image, I know exactly the pixel-indices of the pixels relevant for the outlier detection. I'm currently retrieving the relevant pixels using:

```
idx = Position[dat, 1.];
maskPx = Extract[img // ImageData, idx]
```

Now `maskPx` contains the gray-values of the apple within the mask. I can do the outlier detection, that's not the problem. The problem is: How to get the indices of the pixels which are outliers (and thus need to be removed)? Because I want to map this back and make the mask black at those points/regions. This would yield in this case something like this:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the late reply. @belisarius: The Motivation is: I want to use the grey-values of all the pixels within the red circle (i.e. the pixels that lay behind the white disk-mask) in another algorithm that comes after the masking (thats is a fitting algorithm). But first I want to make sure to detect the outliers correctly and therefore display the mask to the user (just overlaying it with the original image) so that he is able to accept/reject the calculated mask.

Here's one original image:

[image]

Here's the code which will get me to the object detection of the apple and the generated disk-mask:

```
imgneg = ColorNegate[img]
bin = Closing[Binarize[imgneg, Method -> "Cluster"] // ColorNegate // DeleteSmallComponents // FillingTransform, 1] 
{c, r} = 1/.ComponentMeasurements[bin, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]; 
Show[img, Graphics[{Red, Circle[c, r]}]]
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
disk = ColorConvert[ColorNegate@Graphics[{Black, Disk[c, r]}, ImageSize -> {w, h}], "Grayscale"]
dat = disk // ImageData;
```

@nikie: I have NOT implemented it yet because I didn't know how to do it so that I can draw conclusion back onto the pixel-indices. But how I thought to do it was:

```
idx = Position[dat, 1.]; (* Extract the pixel-positions of the white pixels of the disk-mask *)
maskPx = Extract[img // ImageData, idx] (* get grey-values of the original apple-images for the masked pixels *)
```

Now `maskPx` would be a List of grey-values within the region of interest and to remove the outliers I would:

- calculate the mean and the standard deviation of the grey-values within the list
- remove pixels which are too bright, i.e. whose values are too far away from the mean value (i.e. >3*stdev or something like this)

I would receive a cleaned list of greyvalues which I could work with in the following prediction algorithm. The problem is: I only know which greyvalues (the outliers) I'd remove from the original list, but I wouldn't know the position of those outliers within the image to be able to display the mask to the user.

Comment: It's not so difficult, but perhaps it would be better if you explain your motivation.

Comment: Also, please include at least one original, unprocessed image for testing.

Comment: You wrote "I can do the outliner detection" but you didn't give any details: What's the result of your outlier detection? A list of coordinates? A binary image (or 2d array)? Component data from `ComponentMeasurements`? Also: working with lists of indices is often much slower than working with a 2d array containing 0's and 1's (because of vectorization).

Comment: @nikie I think the last image is the desired result. I can't understand the motivation, though.

Comment: By the way, it's spelt *outlier*, that is, a data point that *lies outside* the neighbourhood of the rest of the data.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replys. @belisarius I have added a testing image and the motivation into my original post.

Comment: @nikie: As stated above, I havent implemented it yet. I hope my further details will help to understand it better..

Comment: I don't very sure what you want.Maybe `i=Import@"http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmpar.png";
MaxDetect[i,.06]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a mask like this:

```
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmpar.png"; 
mask = Closing[SelectComponents[MorphologicalBinarize@i,"Area",# > Times@@ImageDimensions@i/2 &], 2];
gs = ColorConvert[ImageMultiply[i, mask], "Grayscale"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then (I still don't understand why you want to do it, but anyway), you could  perform any arithmetic with your Grayscale pixels. For example:

```
(ImageData@gs /. x_ /; x > # -> 0 // Image) & /@ Range[.8, .99, .05]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks gonna try it out tomorrow :-) But looks really promising: short, clean and effective!

Comment: @Öskå Yep, I used it for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032684/353410). But I still feel that the OP here is taking the long road for something quite simple. I _believe_ he's trying to calculate some morphological parameter that can be done without excluding the specular reflections.

Comment: Could be, yes, but unfortunately the `simple` way isn't always simple for a beginner into the new language - no experience how to best combine the different mathematica commands into a working code :(

Comment: @tim That's completely true, and that's why I asked for your motivation. I'm sure we could find a better way if we know what you're trying to get from those images, and not only the intermediate steps.

Comment: Well, I came up with the very simple idea of just using `Binarize` instead of your proposed arithmetic, which also works :-) Dunno why I just didn't think of this simple approach, probably just missed the forest for the trees :D

Comment: @tim `Binarize[]` has a known problem: you need to be sure that the illumination and the reflective properties of the subjects will be highly homogeneous in your experiment. Otherwise YMMV.

Comment: And why is your approach different then Binarize? For me, `/. x_ /; x > # -> 0` looks like replacing values above x>.8 (or .99) with `0` might also be highly dependent on the illumination, isn't it?

Comment: @tim That was only an example reproducing your result. You can perform "any" math with the whole masked image (and not only in an approximate disk)